# How to use Built in system calendar App in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to set a reminder through a flutter app in my default system Calendar App.
Equivalent to intents in Android how can I do it flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](https://pub.dev/packages/device_calendar) package. It claims to have the "Ability to setup reminders for an event" and "add, update or delete events from a calendar", which might fight your needs.